# I want to implement my own custom functionality to <input type="file" id="myFile" />

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc

```
<input type="file" id="myFile" />
```

This line of code brings a textbox & a button. Once clicked, it invokes the system to open its own dialog with buttons "open" & "cancel" to select a particular file with an extension to upload. What I want here is that, while the folders are browsed i want that path to be in the text box, and instead of "open" I want "Ok" button, and once the user clicks "OK" the browse box should disappear. So now I am left with just a path in the text box.

Comment: Might be possible with flash but not with javascript

Comment: I'm pretty sure the text from a fileUploader is controlled by the current User's Language.. I don't believe you can control that..

Comment: So you want a directory selection box rather than file selection?

Comment: exactly eric, so I can use this path to save a file later when another button is clicked on my page

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is not something that can be done unless you use another language. The browser is in charge of the dialog box and what it does - you can't alter that behavior. You can't even do it in flash. I believe you can do something similar to what you are looking for with Java, but I have a feeling that doesn't really help you solve this problem.

Comment: so instead of using the file upload box, can we build our own functionality which does this so that we can control the behavior?

Comment: No. Its not allowed for security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. This dialog is system.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have option to control the dialog properties since it is system generated. You can get the file from the requested postedfile. You may only restrict the file types by using any plugins like jQuery uploadify.

Comment: Note that this is `C:/fakepath/[filename]` in some browsers